# How to match lines that don't end at TM,SL or ZB with regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to match lines that don't end at **TM**,**SL** or **ZB**? I tried `^.*(?<!TM|SL|ZB)$`, but notepad++ says `Find: Invalid regular expression`

Sample:

```
LineKA
LineSL
LineZB
LineDS
LineTM
```

Comment: Try: `^(?!.*(TM|SL|ZB)).*` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4R3EdT/1)

Comment: This does not match the end condition
Try
(?<!(TM|SL|ZB))$

Answer (score 0):

Use this RegEx :

```
^.*(?<!SL)(?<!ZB)(?<!TM)$
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Why do unnecessary matching (^.*) ?